# AWS Lambda times out when trying to connect to sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My lambda times out when trying to connect to SQS. The Lambda has a role that allows it to connect to SQS, but it is located inside a VPC and subnet. What might be the solution to this problem?

I see this error in my logs:

```
[INFO]  2019-10-01T14:29:58.303Z    e8ad5b4e-119a-48c1-b320-1d855c4efb22    Getting SQS queue url from <some_sqs_queue>...
    14:30:16
[CRITICAL]  2019-10-01T14:30:16.743Z    e8ad5b4e-119a-48c1-b320-1d855c4efb22    ## Transmission Error Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/"
```

and this is the relevant code which works locally but not up on the lambda:

```
 sqs = boto3.client(
        'sqs', # region_name="us-west-2",
        aws_access_key_id=credentials.access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
        aws_session_token=credentials.token,
        config=Config(connect_timeout=6, read_timeout=10, retries={'max_attempts': 2})
    )
```

and

```
try:
    logger.info(f"Getting SQS queue url from {sqs_queue}...")
    queue_url = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=sqs_queue)['QueueUrl']
    # iterate over entries in batches of 10
    for batch in [entries[index:index + sqs_batch_limit] for index in range(0, len(entries), sqs_batch_limit)]:
        logger.info(f"Sending batch of {len(batch)} records to sqs...")
        sqs.send_message_batch(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
            Entries=batch
        )
        logger.info("Sent batch of records to sqs successful")
```

It doesn't even get the `sqs_queue_url` but it works locally. What are the possible reasons for this log Transmission Error Connect error?

Comment: I had problems before because resource was in a zone and function in another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda connection to SQS timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073852/aws-lambda-connection-to-sqs-timed-out)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can that the AWS Lambda function "is located inside a VPC and subnet".

However, Amazon SQS exists on the Internet, not in the VPC.

Therefore, you will either need a way for the Lambda function to reach the Internet, or a way to make Amazon SQS available within the VPC.

**Option 1: Allow the AWS Lambda function to reach the Internet**

When a Lambda function is *not* configured to use a VPC, it can communicate directly with the Internet. However, when it *is* configured to use a VPC, it does not have direct access to the Internet.

Instead, the recommended configuration is:

- Attach the Lambda function to the **private subnets** in the VPC
- Launch a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet and update the private Route Table to send Internet-bound traffic via the NAT Gateway

**Option 2: Make Amazon SQS accessible within the VPC**

You can create an [Amazon VPC Endpoint for Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-vpc-endpoints.html) in the VPC:

> If you use Amazon VPC to host your AWS resources, you can establish a connection between your VPC and Amazon SQS. You can use this connection to send messages to your Amazon SQS queues without crossing the public internet.